# How to make multiple tables share the id column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

This question has been asked before but never really answered (at least the way I want to do it). I have three tables in my database, `threads`, `responses` and `votes`. I need them to share the `id` field only. So I can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM threads AS t JOIN responses AS r JOIN votes AS v
WHERE id = 15
```

and will only retrieve a thread a response or (exclusive) a vote record with id = 15.

Is there a possible way to do this without creating an extra table? I'm not asking if it's a good idea (which is probably not), but if it's possible and how to do it.

Comment: SQL tables are flat structures. If they are to share an id by key, each of the three tables needs to have an id column. On one table (probably threads) it is the primary key, and on the other two it is a foreign key back to threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select will throw an error, because the `id` field in the where clause is ambiguous. I suppose there is an `id` field in all of these three tables.

```
SELECT * FROM threads AS t JOIN responses AS r JOIN votes AS v
WHERE id = 15
```

So even if the `id` field is "somehow shared" between these fields, you will have to make your where clause unambiguous:

```
SELECT * FROM threads AS t JOIN responses AS r JOIN votes AS v
WHERE t.id = 15
```

Furthermore, I suppose threads and responses have a many-to-one relationship which means there can be several response corresponding to a single thread. This means the `responses` table would have a `thread_id` field. The `id` field in the `responses` table could not have the same value as the `id` field in the corresponding `thread` record, since the `id` field must be unique in both tables.

The same logic goes to the relationship between `responses` and `votes` (a single response would have many votes).

Hence **I conclude there is no possible way to share the `id` field** between these three tables.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want to fetch thread, or response, or vote with id = 5. There is no opportunity to provide id field uniqueness across tables (i.e. prevent create response and vote with the same id value) in MySQL, but you can do it in your app.

And you can fetch needed row this way:

```
SELECT id, name, 'thread' AS `type` FROM threads WHERE id=5
UNION
SELECT id, name, 'response' AS `type` FROM responses WHERE id=5
UNION 
SELECT id, name, 'vote' AS `type` FROM votes WHERE id=5
```